# Get array out of multi dimension array nested property values

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

Is it possible without using loop but some helper functions

to get `moo` values

```
[1, 3, 5, ....]
```

out of

```
[
  ['moo' => 1, 'foo' => 'A'],
  ['moo' => 3, 'foo' => 'B'], 
  ['moo' => 5, 'foo' => 'C']
]
```

Since I'm using Laravel any of it's helper functions are preferable as solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-pluck

```
array_pluck($your_array, 'moo')
```